# Integrating complex exponentials

Tags: complex-integration

I want to compute the following integral involving complex exponentials but my approach is leading me to problems with infinities.

$$
I = {a \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-bt^2+i \omega t} + e^{-bt^2-i \omega t})\; dt
$$

$$
= {a \over 2} \bigg({e^{-bt^2+i \omega t} \over -2bt+i \omega}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty  + {e^{-bt^2-i \omega t} \over {-2bt-i \omega}}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty\bigg)
$$

This leads to problems with infinities.

Comment: When you take the derivative of your antiderivatives, do you get the original integrands back? (the answer may surprise you) Also, I would recommend looking into the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: Are there good reading material to help handle integrals of Gaussians with proofs?

Comment: The linked article contains the main part of what should be necessary here, is there something else in particular you need?

Comment: Have been working on the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega t) dt$

Comment: Right, and your approach seems perfectly sensible, the article contains what you should need to continue from there. (in fact it contains a generalized formula which would give you the answers for both integrals, from which point you could continue just with algebra)

Comment: If you'd like there's also an alternative method using differentiation under the integral sign, where you differentiate in terms of $\omega$ and then integrate by parts. There's no real need for it but it's always fun to mention

Comment: I do need assistance on the proceeding steps as the Gaussian Integral link does not discuss complex exponents.

Comment: It works out the same way whether the coefficients are complex or not: I can show that real quick

Comment: Could you show that if you please Steve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the general case for the Gaussian integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax^2 + bx + c} dx$$

where $a,b,$ and $c$ are complex and $\text{Re}(a) < 0.$

We can begin by completing the square in the exponent to bring the integral closer to the original $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ case: just as in the real numbers, we have $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 +(c - \frac{b^2}{4a}).$ Plugging this in:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax^2 + bx + c} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 +(c - \frac{b^2}{4a})} dx = e^{c - \frac{b^2}{4a}} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2} dx$$

using the exponent rule $e^{x + y} = e^x + e^y$ and pulling out a constant by the linearity of the integral.

Now we can proceed with the typical argument: $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2} dx, I^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 + a(y + \frac{b}{2a})^2} dy dx = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} e^{a(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 + a(y + \frac{b}{2a})^2} dA$$

We can modify our switch to polar coordinates slightly to accommodate for the extra term: let $x = r\cos\theta - \frac{b}{2a}$ and $y = r\sin\theta - \frac{b}{2a}.$ Because the only change is a constant, the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ are unchanged, and so is the Jacobian:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}x_r & x_\theta \\ y_r & y_\theta\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\det J = (\cos\theta)(r\cos\theta) - (\sin\theta)(-r\sin\theta) = r \cos^2\theta + r \sin^2\theta = r$$
$$I^2 = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{ar^2} r dr d\theta$$

We can recognize the innermost integrand as $\frac1{2a} \frac{d}{dr} e^{ar^2},$ so using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the defintion of our indefinite integral we have $\int_0^\infty e^{ar^2} r dr = \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{2a} (e^{ab^2} - 1).$ By linearity (assuming for the moment that the required limits exist) this is equivalent to $\frac1{2a}[(\lim_{b \to \infty} e^{ab^2}) - 1].$

Let $a = s + it$ for real $s,t,$ noting that we've required $s < 0.$ Applying Euler's theorem, we have that $e^{ab^2} = e^{sb^2}\cdot e^{itb^2} = e^{sb^2}(\cos(tb^2) + i\sin(tb^2)).$ The squeeze theorem can now be applied to the real and imaginary parts to show that both go to $0,$ so the limit is $0.$

So we have:

$$I^2 = \int_0^{2\pi} -\frac{1}{2a} d\theta = -\frac\pi a \to I = \sqrt{- \frac \pi a}$$

and plugging back into our original form:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax^2 + bx + c} dx = e^{c - \frac{b^2}{4a}}\sqrt{\frac \pi{-a}}$$

for $\text{Re}(a) < 0.$

---

Applying this to your case in particular we get $$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-at^2}\cos(\omega t) dt = \int_{\mathbb R}\frac12(e^{-at^2+i\omega t} + e^{-at^2-i\omega t}) dt = \frac12\left(e^{-\frac{(i\omega)^2}{4(-a)}}\sqrt{\frac\pi {-(-a)}} + e^{-\frac{(-i\omega)^2}{4(-a)}}\sqrt{\frac\pi {-(-a)}}\right) = \boxed{e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{4a}}\sqrt{\frac\pi a}}$$

---

We can corroborate this result using an alternative method. Let $I(a, \omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-at^2}\cos(\omega t) dt.$ By the above style of argument we know that $I(a, 0) = \sqrt{\frac \pi a}.$

Now suppose we were to take a partial derivative with respect to $\omega.$ By the Leibniz rule of integration, we should be able to pull the derivative into the integral as follows:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\omega} I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial\omega} e^{-at^2}\cos(\omega t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -te^{-at^2}\sin(\omega t) dt$$

We can use the extra $t$ to do integration by parts:

$$u = \sin(\omega t), dv = -te^{-at^2} dt$$
$$du = \omega \cos(\omega t) dt, v = \frac1{2a}e^{-at^2}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -te^{-at^2}\sin(\omega t) dt = \frac1{2a}\sin(\omega t)e^{-at^2}\Big|^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac\omega{2a}e^{-at^2}\cos(\omega t) dt$$

Note that the integral we end up with is the same as our definition of $I,$ so substituting it in as $I$ we get:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} I = -\frac{\omega}{2a} I$$

which can easily be solved as follows:

$$\frac1I \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} I = -\frac{\omega}{2a}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} (\ln I) = -\frac{\omega}{2a}$$
$$\ln I = -\frac{\omega^2}{4a} + f_1(a)$$
$$I = f_2(a)e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{4a}}$$
$$I(a, 0) = \sqrt{\frac \pi a} \Rightarrow I(a, \omega) = \sqrt{\frac \pi a} \cdot e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{4a}}$$

Comment: Apologies for the delay, answer got a bit long

Comment: Don't apologise Stephen.  I expected things to be quite involved.  Could you advice on any text or book that handles equations with complex coefficients (e.g. polynomials) I can introspect, if there exist ones?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, but is there a particular question you have regarding polynomials with complex coefficients?

Comment: Somehow I need to elevate my skills on Theory of Equations to the complex cases (including complex coefficients), with a decent amount of proofs.  Have only really seen books focused on coefficients in R.

Comment: My suggestion regarding that would just be to look closer at the manipulations you use on equations with real coefficients and see where the same manipulations are valid for equations with complex coefficients. Given some of the shared properties, the answer is often yes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is easier to see here that the integrals are Fourier transforms.

$${a \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-bt^2+i \omega t} + e^{-bt^2-i \omega t})\; dt =\\
= \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-bt^2+i \omega t} dt + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-bt^2-i \omega t} dt \right) =\\
=\frac{a}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi} \left( \mathcal{F}(e^{-bt^2})(\omega) + \mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-bt^2})(\omega) \right) = \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi} \frac{\sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{\omega ^2}{4 b}}}{\sqrt{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } a e^{-\frac{\omega ^2}{4 b}}}{\sqrt{b}},$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is a Fourier transform and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is
a inverse Fourier transform. We can find Fourier transforms for the desired functions from the special tables. Tables of some Fourier transforms can be viewed, for example, on Wikipedia.

Comment: I am familiar with Fourier Transform, making the approach very nice.